# How do I save a string in android and recall it afterwards?

Tags: java, android

Beginner question, but I have been looking around about SQLite and internal date storage  but basically I didn't understand anything in the past half hour.

I want particular strings to be saved,

```
if (breadExists){
    String bread = edittext.getText().toString();
}
```

Now I want that string to be remembered by the application and recalled at a certain point. I believe that SQLite databases might be more helpful since I have a lot of these functions but I have no idea about how data saving works on android so maybe internal storage is better.

How do I make the string "bread" be remembered whenever prompted by the application?

Comment: Read this and choose what's the best way for you : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: I suggest the shared preferences method. (In the link above) since you are storing little amount of data

Comment: I did read that. SQLite seems like the best way but I have literally NO experience with SQL.

Comment: @Doomsknight, the string in edittext can be pretty lengthy under some circumstances

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use shared preferences to save your string, it's very easy.
To save string, use following code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( "appData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE );
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = getSharedPreferences( "appData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE ).edit();
prefEditor.putString( "bread", bread );
prefEditor.commit();
```

To retrieve the string, use following code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences( "appData", Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE );
String bread = sharedPref.getString( "bread", "no string" );
```